# What's a word for someone who is constantly asking for same thing?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

Hi I'm looking for a word for someone who is constantly asking for something and keeps wanting updates about it. The closest words I can think of is pushy and, to a lesser extent, annoying. But clearly these words don't directly mean what I intend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Importunate**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/importunate) - making repeated or annoying requests or demands

[**Persistent**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persistent) - continuing to do something or to try to do something even though it is difficult or other people want you to stop